# How is mass of observable universe calculated?

Tags: experimental-physics, mass, astrophysics, dark-matter, observable-universe

How is even mass of earth known ? How do we get to know them? Whilst I was studying about dark matter it was listed about 'mass of observable universe' and density and so on...so what is the procedure???

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? Are you asking how we determine the mass of the Earth, or how we determine the masses of all celestial bodies, or how we estimate the mass of the observable universe. These are very different questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do people calculate proportions of dark matter, dark energy and baryonic matter of the universe?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69157/)

Comment: Well observable universe..I will post earth in a separate ques.