# Does dark matter / dark energy could be simply regular mattter

Tags: dark-matter, dark-energy

First of all I'm not a physist, my formation is related to Information Systems but I was always curious regarding the laws that rules our universe.

I would like to apologize as well for my bad english since it is not my mother language.

Recently I watched a video from professor Michio Kaku which makes me curious about the lack of information related to dark energy / dark matter.

To start with I would like to think that before the big bang, nothing else existed, even the empty space, so everything was concentrated in a single high density ball of pure energy with a mass tending to be infinite.

When the big bang took place, this ball of energy expanded in all directions, expanding the own space and everything inside trough all directions.
Today we know that nothing can go faster than speed of light, however this afirmation is based on the fact that the light is travelling on vacuum or empty space.

Considering a supposition that our own dimension was created together with the big bang including the space, this law may not be applied at the very first moments after the big bang since the objects could be travelling ahead of the speace itself.

If we consider that during the big bang, 80% of the energy released started travelling faster than light in all directions, creating the own space on it's way, and then we had the remaining matter travelling below the speed of light behind it.

Since nothing on space can travel faster than speed on light, we can not see the objects that initially started travelling faster than speed of light, however their gravitional effects can be feel at the the galaxies near the boundaries of the universe which are being pulled away from each otther.

The big questions about dark energy and dark matter is that something should exist otherwise galaxies won't have enough mass to be formed as well as the fact that the speed the universe is expanding is increasing over time.
If instead of having dark energy acting on the space between the matter, we have simply a massive amount of matter outside the know boundaries of our universe pulling the galaxies away from the centre of the universe, could this be a plausible solution for the dark matter / dark energy question?

Again sorry for the stupid question, but it was something that came into my mind and even after looking for answers on internet I could find anything related to it.

Comment: No. Ordinary matter does not fit the evidence. If it did there would be no mystery in the first place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't dark matter just matter?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1008/)

Comment: @sammygerbil: you state authoritatively and you don't provide relevant arguments. The OP made some effort, he deserves better than a stone

Comment: you may be interested by [How do people calculate proportions of dark matter, dark energy and baryonic matter of the universe?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69157/how-do-people-calculate-proportions-of-dark-matter-dark-energy-and-baryonic-mat) which is another way to answer you question

Comment: @igael : Each of the 2 sentences in my comment is a relevant argument. The link provides the detail. The OP is not a physicist but thinks he might have found an obvious explanation which the physics community has overlooked. As he says, a stupid question.

Comment: @sammygerbil : *If it did there would be no mystery in the first place.* : is this relevant ? the link of next comment is not concerned by the remark. And you began with *No. Ordinary matter does not fit the evidence*. More authoritative, I don't know

Comment: @igael : Of course it is relevant. If ordinary matter explained what Dark Matter and Dark Energy have been posited to explain, this question would not have been asked. Likewise if the US government openly admitted the Moon Landings were faked, there would be no conspiracy theory claiming they were faked... The top-rated answer in the link starts : "There is a very precise reason why dark planets made of 'ordinary matter' (baryons - particles made up of 3 quarks) cannot be the dark matter." Which is exactly what I claimed in my comment. Is that also too authoritative for you also?

Comment: @sammygerbil: I commented the form of your poor post and now, you are arguing on the subject ...